# Accessing Objects in JSON Array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value)

I have a service that returns nested Objects in a JSON Array. How can I loop through the objects and print the desired data?

This is my result:

```
[
{
    "item1": {
        "sourceUuid": "5599ffac-4b99-47c7-9370-a25e7e465429",
        "targetUuid": "5599ffac-4b99-47c7-9370-a25e7effffff"
    }
},
{
    "item2": {
        "sourceUuid": "bf63fe50-8b2b-488d-b565-009fcaebdb45",
        "targetUuid": "-1"
    }
},
{
    "item3": {
        "sourceUuid": "0005fd96-f654-4781-8602-09fedc0cdd35",
        "targetUuid": "0005fd96-f654-4781-8602-09fedc0cdd35"
    }
}
]
```

This is what I want to print for each item (item1, item2, item3, ...):

```
Item Name: item1
Source: 5599ffac-4b99-47c7-9370-a25e7e465429
Target: 5599ffac-4b99-47c7-9370-a25e7effffff
```

So far I tried:

```
for (var i = 0, length = data.length; i < length; i++) {
for (obj in data[i]) {
    console.log(obj);

}
}
```

This only returns "item1", "item2" etc. But I don't know how access sourceUuid etc. from there

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can loop the array with a [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) and the object properties with [for-in loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

```
for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++)
    for (var name in result[i]) {
        console.log("Item name: "+name);
        console.log("Source: "+result[i][name].sourceUuid);
        console.log("Target: "+result[i][name].targetUuid);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a loop

```
for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; ++i){
   //do something with obj[i]
   for(var ind in obj[i]) {
        console.log(ind);
        for(var vals in obj[i][ind]){
            console.log(vals, obj[i][ind][vals]);
        }
   }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/pngmL/

Comment: i would like to use it in jade after. Or angularjs.