# Getting values from JSON objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a file named AnimalsData that has an object that consists of an array. The array consists of an object and another array. It looks like this:

```
var animals = {
    animalClass : [
        {
            className : "Reptiles", 
            animalArray : [
                {   
                    image1 : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/76/Coast_Garter_Snake.jpg/500px-Coast_Garter_Snake.jpg",
                    image2 : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5b/Nerodia_sipedon_shedding.JPG/440px-Nerodia_sipedon_shedding.JPG",
                    name : "Snake", 
                    description : 
                }, "blah, blah, blah"
                {   
                    image1 : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f9/Crocodilia_collage.jpg/600px-Crocodilia_collage.jpg",
                    image2 : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3e/Caiman_crocodilus_Tropicario_2.JPG/440px-Caiman_crocodilus_Tropicario_2.JPG",
                    name : "Crocodilia", 
                    description : "blah, blah, blah"
            }, 
            {   
                    image1 : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/18/Bartagame_fcm.jpg/500px-Bartagame_fcm.jpg",
                    image2 : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9e/Lizard_in_Yemen.JPG/440px-Lizard_in_Yemen.JPG",
                    name : "Lizard", 
                    description : "blah, blah, blah"
                }, 
                {   
                    image1 : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/86/Chelonia_mydas_is_going_for_the_air.jpg/440px-Chelonia_mydas_is_going_for_the_air.jpg",
                    image2 : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1d/Turtle3m.JPG/500px-Turtle3m.JPG",
                    name : "Turtle", 
                    description : "blah, blah, blah"
                }, 
            ]
        },
        .......etc., etc
```

My HTML file looks like this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Animal Photo Album</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="js/handlebars-v3.0.3.js"></script>-->

    <script src="js/AnimalsData.js"></script>
    <script src="js/assignment.js"></script>        

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/myjavascript.css" rel="stylesheet">     
</head>
<body>      
    <main id="content" class="container">
    </main>         
</body>
```

I'm trying to get the values of the className object from the animalClass array. I have been using the following two stackoverflow pages as a guide:

[Accessing Objects in JSON Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217790/accessing-objects-in-json-array-javascript) and [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

I have another javascript file which has the following:

***EDIT*** I changed "name" in the for in loop and the jQuery statement to className in order to reduce the confusion.

```
function executeObject() {
    for(var i = 0; i < animals.animalClass.length; i++) {
        for(var className in animals.animalClass[i].className) {
            $('<p>' + ClassName + '</p>').insertAfter('#content');
        }                   
    }
};

$(function(){   
    executeObject();
});
```

However, this only produces numbers. I've tried various tweaks to the above but they either end up being undefined or the insert "className" and "animalArray" three times. The examples looked pretty straight forward but I'm obviously missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
function executeObject() {
    for(var i = 0; i < animals.animalClass.length; i++) {
     $('<p>' +  animals.animalClass[i].className + '</p>').insertAfter('#content');                 
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am attempting to access the values in className which is not in the animalArray. It appears that I created confusion by using "name" instead of className. My apologies. I have made the appropriate edits to my code.

Comment: That did it. Thank you. I see where I went wrong now.

Answer (score 2):

You are referencing the className, not the animals array.

```
function executeObject() {
    for(var i = 0; i < animals.animalClass.length; i++) {
        var name = animals.animalClass[i].className;
        $('<p>' + name + '</p>').insertAfter('#content');
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am attempting to access the values in className which is not in the animalArray. It appears that I created confusion by using "name" instead of className. My apologies. I have made the appropriate edits to my code.

Comment: I have fixed my answer. So, you don't even need the second loop. You just need to access the className variable inside the first 'for' loop.

Answer (score 0):

Do something along these lines.

```
for(var i=0; i<=animals.animalClass.length; i++){
    var animal_class = animals.animalClass[i];
    console.log(animal_class.animalArray);
    for(var j=0; j<=animal_class.animalArray.length; j++){
        console.log(animal_class.animalArray[j].name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am attempting to access the values in className which is not in the animalArray. It appears that I created confusion by using "name" instead of className. My apologies. I have made the appropriate edits to my code.