# how to get specific value in JSON array with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, getjson

As you see in the image:

[image]

I've a array of object I think there is JSON array. I want to get only "productThumbnailUrl" on this array and use that in another way.

Can anyone help me to get this value and store it in a separate variable.

It's has multiple rows on the array. I only want get "productThumbnailUrl".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing Objects in JSON Array (JavaScript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217790/accessing-objects-in-json-array-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `For` loop to loop json data

```
for(x in json) {
    console.log(json[x].productThumbnailUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

var x = JSON.parse('{"productThumbnailUrl": "val1", "key2": "val2", "key3": "val3", "key4": "val4"}');

alert (x['productThumbnailUrl']);

var y = x['productThumbnailUrl'];

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider your main array is

```
var products= [your product arr];
products.forEach(
function(product){
console.log(product["productThumbnailUrl"]);
});
```

it will list your productThumbnailUrls. it will loop through all items.

Comment: `var json = $.cookie('cartArray');
    var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
    var arr = [];

    for(var x in parsed){
      arr.push(parsed[x]);
    }
    for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
      arr[i]['productThumbnailUrl'];
    }`